Is Chougoukin New Z also made of Japanium?
Supposedly, Mazinger Z was made with an alloy called Chōgokin Zetto ( Super-Alloy Z) . This alloy is made of Japanium, a new element only found in Mount Fuji. In a movie, where Mazinger Z was destroyed, a similar looking robot called Great Mazinger Z came to the rescue and saved the day. The Great Mazinger Z was more powerful than Mazinger Z, and one of the reasons probably is Mazinger Z was made with Chōgokin Zetto ( Super-Alloy Z) , when the Great Mazinger Z was made of Chougoukin New Z (New Super-Alloy Z)
Is this new Alloy that probably made The Great Mazinger Z more powerful than his predecesor, also made of Japanium, or is it made with other elements?
